# Can I have live agent button and invitation on same page?

Tags: liveagent

Is it possible to use live agent chat button and chat invitation on the same page.

Say for instance be like this, I have a page where I have a chat button in place that is working. Now I am trying to add a automated invitation on the same page, which I am not able to do currently.

Is this scenario possible to be achieved?

Thanks
**Hariharan N**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is. as long as you have them both in the same deployment and you have the deployment code in the page it should work fine